# Batch run script when closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, exit, exit-code

My question is how would I make a batch script instead of closing when the X in the top right is pressed to execute a file called exit.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [X] is "out of reach" for `cmd`. Only way, I can think of is: create another `cmd` to watch the presence of the current window:

```
@echo off
title WatchMe
more +7 %~f0 >t2.bat
start "watcher" t2.bat

exit /b

@echo off
:running
tasklist /v|find "WatchMe" >nul &&echo waiting || goto finished
timeout 1 >nul
goto running
:finished
echo "the process has finished
```

Comment: This method does not differentiate if the cmd.exe window terminate normally or terminate because the X was pressed...

Comment: correct, @Aacini. But my window is still usable after the script finished... ok, unlikely that this is, what the OP wants. Point for you ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple points in this question that are not clear enough:

- If you want that when the rigth top X is pressed on the cmd.exe window it not close, but do a different thing instead, then there is *no way* to achieve such thing with any existent window, that is, with the windows of all existent applications.
- If you want to *differentiate* if the window that execute your Batch file terminated normally or terminated because the user click on the right top X, then the way to achieve that is via a previous "starter" program that execute your Batch file and expects a certain value returned from it. If the returned value is not the expected one, then it is assumed that the window was cancelled via the right top X.

**starter.bat:**

```
@echo off

echo Start yourScript.bat:
start "" /W yourScript.bat
echo Value returned from the script: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% neq 12345 ECHO execute exit.exe
```

**yourScript.bat:**

```
@echo off

echo I am the script.bat
set /P var=input value:

rem Terminate normally:
exit 12345
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to detect if the X is pressed.

Comment: @09stephenb: there is no way to catch the [X] button. to use a picture: "I want my Windows to run a file, when I disconnect the power-cable". Aacinis solution checks for the (unexpected) end of the batchfile, my solution checks for the existence of the window (well, the window-title to be exact)