# Batch files can not supress "terminate job"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to open a 2nd batch file and detect if it normally exited or closed by a user (ctrl+c or x or window termiate etc..)
so Im using this following example by [Batch run script when closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559901/batch-run-script-when-closed)

```
@Echo off
set errorlevel=1

    start /w %comspec% /c "mode 70,10&title Folder Confirmation Box&color 1e&echo.&echo. Else the close window&pause>NUL&exit 12345"
    echo %errorlevel%
    pause
```

Im trying to keep 1st batch waiting (/W) since I will check for errorlevel later on
But after closing the 2nd batch file I get an error like ^cterminate batch job (Y/N)?

I tried the suggestion over https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation

with the script

```
rem Bypass "Terminate Batch Job" prompt.
if "%~2"=="-FIXED_CTRL_C" (
   REM Remove the -FIXED_CTRL_C parameter
   SHIFT
) ELSE (
   REM Run the batch with <NUL and -FIXED_CTRL_C
   CALL <NUL %1 -FIXED_CTRL_C %*
   GOTO :EOF
)
```

That works quite fine 
So is there a way of starting from same batch file and avoiding the terminating?
Or do I have to create a new batch from same batch and call it?
(I don't want them to see the file aswell)

Comment: For reference, the [cause of the problem is described here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444765/why-does-a-non-interactive-batch-script-think-ive-pressed-control-c)  Not a duplicate, because the OP here needs a workaround for his particular scenario rather than just an explanation of why it happens.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not assign values to a [volatile environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) like `errorlevel` using `set` command. Doing that causes it becomes unvolatile in current context.
2. [Always use *title*](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) in `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`.
3. `start "" /W cmd /c "anycommand&exit /B 12345"` *always* returns `12345` exit code. It's because all the cmd line with `&` concatenated commands is prepared in parsing time (the same as a command block enclosed in parentheses) and then run entirely, indivisibly. Omit `&exit /B 12345` to get proper exit code from `anycommand`, or replace it with something like `start "" /W cmd /c "anycommand&&exit /B 12345||exit /B 54321"` to get only success/failure indication.

Next code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

set "_command=2nd_batch_file.bat"
:: for debugging purposes
set "_command=TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK"

:: raise errorlevel 9009 as a valid file name can't contain a vertical line 
invalid^|command>nul 2>&1

echo before %errorlevel%
start "" /w %comspec% /C "mode 70,10&title Folder Confirmation Box&color 1e&echo(&echo( Else the close window&%_command%" 
echo after  %errorlevel%
```

**Output** shows sample `%_command%` exit codes: `0` or `1` if came to an end properly but `-1073741510` if terminated forceably by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> or red <kbd>×</kbd>

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31866091.bat<nul
before 9009
after  0

==>D:\bat\SO\31866091.bat<nul
before 9009
after  1

==>D:\bat\SO\31866091.bat<nul
before 9009
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
after  -1073741510

==>
```

Comment: You're still getting the Terminate batch job (Y/N) prompt, though, which is what the OP is trying to eliminate.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't think that _message_ matters: _Im trying to open a 2nd batch file_ and **detect if it normally exited or closed by a user**

Comment: *But after closing the 2nd batch file I get an error like ^cterminate batch job (Y/N)?*  and  *So is there a way of starting from same batch file and avoiding the terminating?*

Comment: ... and the title of the question is a bit of a clue too. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston but displaying this message is hard-coded in Windows, I agree BinaryMisfit's answer: [this behavior is by design and controlled by the command interpreter. There is no method of "mapping" or even "intercepting" this unless you de-compile and recompile the interpreter directly](http://superuser.com/a/35701/376602).

Comment: If there's no solution, then the answer is that there's no solution.  But I don't think that's true; at the very least, we can prevent the script from waiting for the user to answer yes or no.

Comment: It turns out that it is possible; see my answer, which uses a variant on Gringo Suave's answer to the linked question.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue with `errorlevel` and that it is always wise to include a title with the `start` command.  I hadn't spotted either of those.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
call :runme start /w "Child Process" %comspec% /c "child.bat & exit 12345" <NUL >NUL 2>NUL 
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
goto :eof

:runme
%*
goto :eof
```

The idea is to call a subroutine in the current script rather than calling out to an external script.  You can still redirect input and output for a subroutine call.

Comment: +1 ? although the `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?` redirected somewhere, pressing the `Enter` or `Ctrl+C` return the same exit code of `12345` so where's the OP's request to detect and differentiate them ?  (only red `×` returns different exit code). However, let the OP to distinguish or combine our answers...

Comment: @JosefZ: that turns out to be an artifact of the `pause` command.  If we run a child batch script as per the OPs scenario it doesn't happen.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is the intent here to detect whether child.bat exited normally, for which `exit 12345` sets the exit code to a known value? An abnormal exit could be from closing the child console window, which sets the exit code to `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (-1073741510). Terminating child.bat via Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break in the child console sets the exit code to 255 or 1. Redirecting stdin to NUL in the parent short circuits the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" prompt and effectively answers no. Redirecting stdout and stderr to NUL hides the latter prompt.

Comment: @eryksun, I don't really remember.  I think the `exit 12345` may have been included  in my answer simply because it appears in the question.  I suppose it is necessary if you don't know what exit code `child.bat` returns, but still want to determine whether `child.bat` exited naturally or was aborted.